# MAGENTO 2 remove sidebar.main sidebar.aditional with xml update does not work

Tags: xml, magento-2.1.7, layout-update, sidebar

So I have the in my category->Display Settings->Display Mode set to `"Static block only"`

And **category->Design->Layout set** to `"1 column"`

And **category->Design->Layout** Update XML

```
   <referenceContainer name="content">
     <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
     <referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
   </referenceContainer >
```

And sidebar.additional doesn't get removed, But what I notice is if I remove only one of them at time it works but I need to remove both.

What am I dong wrong with the xml updated?

Any help Please Appreciate.

Comment: if you have set 1 column layout, by default it should not display sidebar(left/right column)

Comment: Do you have installed any theme in your magento?

Comment: @Piyush   Yes that's what I thought but there might be a bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7765

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI Yes I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only solution It worked for me was xml update by removing `catalog.leftnav`  e.g

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
     <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>
 </referenceContainer >
```

Comment: For me changing reference container to `<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">` has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
```

without wrapping in `<referenceContainer name="content">` and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

In case, i am suggesting to make Anchor field Value at Display Setting to NO .

```
,Bcoz by default at magento2Anchor field value is set As YES.
```

I have also check same scenario at magento 1.X.If you category has Products and Display Setting* to YES and Display setting is only static block.Then on left panel ,you will layer navigations and right section CMS static block.

Comment: setting isAnchor to= NO  works for my Magento2.1.0 but does not work for 2.1.7

Comment: have check the setting at  store view scope?

Comment: @ Amit Bera there are no store view set only the default. However when I set the isAnchor to =NO it's seen to display a diferent template layout with id="narrow-by-list2" when before was narrow-by-list